# Vmware credential errors with zabbix check

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, zabbix

I want to monitor my vmware infrastructure with Zabbix.

I follow https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/vm_monitoring, but i doesn't have any new hosts or VM

i have this error in log :

Item [VCENTER.mydomain.lan:vmware.version[{$URL}]] error: Unable to make a connection because the user name or password is incorrect

My configuration :

```
- Zabbix 2.2.5 (installed via RPM on a Centos 6.5)
- vcenter 5.5 (self-signed certificate)

- StartVMwareCollectors = 1
- VMwareCacheSize = 16M
- VMwareFrequency = 60

- {$URL} = https://VCENTER.mydomain.lan/sdk
- {$USERNAME} = monitoring@vsphere.local
- {$PASSWORD} = xxxxx
```

I can connect with this account on vsphere web client. I also try with administrator@vsphere.local, and my AD account.
I also try on the ESXi (with the root account).

curl -k -I https://VCENTER.mydomain.lan/sdk give me "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too stupid ... Typo error with "{$USERNAME}" ...

Comment: Okay, I have updated mine with $ instead of # - but I had problems with the @ in username, and when switching to the domain\username, it began to work again.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define the username as MYDomain\MyUser

E.g.

```
{$USERNAME}  => "vsphere.local\monitoring"
```

Zabbix has a bug if you use @ in the username.

Comment: I have already try it, but it fail also ...